# RecyclerView in NestedScrollView to fill remaining space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have view hierarchy like below:
**NestedScrollView > ConstraintLayout > [Layout,Layout, RecyclerView]**

I want my RecyclerView to fill remaining space in Nested ScrollView. 
My ConstaintLayout has **wrap_content** layout_height. Child Layouts has fixed height set in dp units. And I want to set RecyclerView height to adjust remaining space inside ConstraintLayout.

I am setting height of ConstraintLayout programatically to calculated value like height of both child Layouts + Screen Height. I nearly works, but RecyclerView with current wrap_content height seem to stretch out of its parent ConstraintLayout boundaries not fitting its bottom margin. If I constraint to bottom of parent ConstrintLayout then it is moved over the above child Layouts content. If I set 0dp height of RecyclerView then it has 0dp height not streching inside available space. Maybe only option is to set height of RecyclerView to fixed dp size programatically ex. onMeasure(), onLayout or other callback methods in Views, Fragments, etc?

Any Idea?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".ui.billing.BillingFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.domain.AppName.base.ui.billing.BillingNestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        android:background="@color/theMinteFormBackground">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <com.domain.AppName.base.utils.design.ShadowLayout
                android:id="@+id/creditCardSectionLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                myapp:sl_shadow_color="#AAD4D4D4"
                myapp:sl_shadow_angle="360"
                myapp:sl_shadow_distance="0dp"
                myapp:sl_shadow_radius="4dp"
                myapp:sl_shadow_top="true"
                myapp:sl_shadow_bottom="true"
                myapp:sl_shadow_right="true"
                myapp:sl_shadow_left="true"
                myapp:sl_shadowed="true">
                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white">

                    <com.domain.AppName.base.ui.forms.FormHeaderView
                        android:id="@+id/creditCardHeaderFormView"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        myapp:labelText="@string/billing_payment_info_section_header"
                        style="@style/FormSectionHeaderStyle" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cancelCreditCardButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/payment_info_form_cancel_button_title"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/creditCardHeaderFormView"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/creditCardHeaderFormView"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/creditCardHeaderFormView"
                        style="@style/CancelCreditCardButtonStyle"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/scanCreditCardButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/payment_info_form_scan_card_button_title"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/creditCardHeaderFormView"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/creditCardHeaderFormView"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/creditCardHeaderFormView"
                        style="@style/ScanCreditCardButtonStyle" />

                    <com.domain.AppName.base.ui.forms.material.ValidableCardNumberInput
                        android:id="@+id/cardNumberInput"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/creditCardHeaderFormView"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

                        myapp:hintText="@string/payment_info_form_card_number_label"
                        myapp:inputType="number"
                        myapp:inputText=""
                        myapp:iconDrawable="@drawable/baseline_credit_card_24"

                        myapp:isRequired="true"
                        myapp:validationEmptyError="@string/validation_card_number_empty"
                        myapp:requireType="none"
                        myapp:validationError="@string/validation_card_number_error"
                        myapp:validationErrorColor="@color/theMinteValidationError" />

                    <com.domain.AppName.base.ui.forms.material.ValidableExpiryDateInput
                        android:id="@+id/expirationDateInput"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardNumberInput"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

                        myapp:hintText="@string/payment_info_form_expiration_date_label"
                        myapp:inputType="number"
                        myapp:inputText=""

                        myapp:isRequired="true"
                        myapp:validationEmptyError="@string/validation_expiration_date_empty"
                        myapp:requireType="regex"
                        myapp:regexPattern="\\d{1,2}/\\d{2,4}"
                        myapp:validationError="@string/validation_expiration_date_error"
                        myapp:validationErrorColor="@color/theMinteValidationError" />

                    <com.domain.AppName.base.ui.forms.material.ValidableTextInput
                        android:id="@+id/cvcTextInput"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/expirationDateInput"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"

                        myapp:hintText="@string/payment_info_form_cvc_label"
                        myapp:inputType="number"
                        myapp:inputText=""

                        myapp:isRequired="true"
                        myapp:validationEmptyError="@string/validation_cvc_empty"
                        myapp:requireType="none"
                        myapp:minLength="3"
                        myapp:maxLength="4"
                        myapp:validationError="@string/validation_cvc_error"
                        myapp:validationErrorColor="@color/theMinteValidationError" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.domain.AppName.base.utils.design.ShadowLayout>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/googlePayFormView"
                layout="@layout/view_google_pay"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="82dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/creditCardSectionLayout" />

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="100dp"
               android:layout_margin="16dp"

               android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"


               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/googlePayFormView" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.domain.AppName.base.ui.billing.BillingNestedScrollView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post XML code?

Comment: If  I modify RecyclerView layout_height to fixed 100dp then recycler view is display correctly i.e. has 100dp and 16dp margin below it inside ConstraintLayout. But setting wrap_content or 0dp to fill available space inside parent ConstraintLayout doesn't work. I am configuring height inside BillingNestedView of ConstraintLayout to fixed size depending on size of device

Answer (score 7):

`android:fillViewport="true"` on the `NestedScrollView` is forcing the inner `ConstraintLayout` to fill the remaining space. You can constrain the bottom view to the bottom of the `ConstraintLayout` and constrain the bottom of the `RecyclerView` to the top of the bottom view. Set `match_constraints` on the `RecyclerView` so it fills the available space - something like this mock-up of your layout.

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/creditCardSectionLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/googlePayFormView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="82dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/creditCardSectionLayout" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/googlePayFormView" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```